# Cloud Run trying to access AndroidPublisher with service account getting - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a ktor kotlin container happily running on Google Cloud Run that is using the Firebase admin library to access a Firebase database and this is all working fine.

We've subsequently added subscriptions to our Android App and want to perform the final acknowledgement on the Cloud Run container after updating a few things. I performed the following:

1. I created a service account with the "Service Account User".
2. Granted Access to the service account to on the Google Play Console - giving only permission to access "Financial data" (I have also given the service full Admin permission but the error is still present).
3. I have changed the price of every subscription (Monetize->Subscriptions) because a few posts on google suggested this might work.

We are sending a valid purchase token from the Android App but keep on getting:

```
401 Unauthorized
POST https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.app.name/purchases/subscriptions/sub_monthly_5_test/tokens/lbggdfiogmjfkiihemijkphc.AO-J1Owrl-ZrgJECocKyAOwxcrgtWxx-5Bbl_MD0ac4s1uGTZVE05TX1iIX-H6Vd6wxEsCTF9DVHrhVEDxpNET_MDeiNjWStyxp9d4wi3DwdZKv7vNxyMv0:acknowledge
```

when trying to access the Google Developer API. Here is a copy of the relevant gradle import and code:

```
    implementation( "com.google.apis:google-api-services-androidpublisher:v3-rev20211021-1.32.1")
```

```
class GoogleClient {
    private fun log(message: Any) = LoggerFactory.getLogger("GoogleClient").info(message.toString())

    private lateinit var androidPublisher: AndroidPublisher

    init {
        try {
            log("GoogleClient init")
            val service = this::class.java.getResourceAsStream("/certs.json")
            val credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(service)
                .createScoped(AndroidPublisherScopes.ANDROIDPUBLISHER)
            androidPublisher = AndroidPublisher.Builder(
                GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
                GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials)
            ).setApplicationName("Subs backend").build()
            log("GoogleClient init success")
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            // Error logging
        }
    }

    suspend fun acknowledgePayment(productToken: String, productId) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        log("acknowledgePayment")
        val response = async {
            val content = SubscriptionPurchasesAcknowledgeRequest()
            androidPublisher.purchases().subscriptions().acknowledge("com.app.name", productId, productToken, content).execute()
            log(content)
        }
        response.await()
    }
}
```

I changed `com.app.name` for security but I am using the proper name of my app that is shown in the Google Play Dashboard.

I also tried to create a service account with the blanket Editor permission and I get the same `401 Unauthorized` error.

**Edit:**
I'm also struggling to find any logs to do with this.

**Update 5/11/21:**
Apologies for the late replies - I think the permissions are correct:

Screenshot from google cloud console IAM->Service Accounts,
[image]
Google Play Console #1
[image]
Google Play Console #2
[image]
Google Play Console API Access page
[image]

I also created a new subscription as apparently that sometimes helps.

Comment: Are you sure that the service account email is authorized to access this API?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Updated the post with screenshots - let me know if there are any more that will be useful.

Comment: Did you activated the API? in your cert.json file, is it the correct project in it? the correct service account?

Answer (score 0):

As guillaume blaquiere mentioned, you need to make sure your service account is authorized.

You can verify this with [`gcloud auth list`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/list) command.

If your account is not credentialed, you'll need to follow the [authentication guide](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#set_up_the_service_account).

Comment: Can someone elaborate on how to verify a service account authorization?

Comment: Hi @DrZaphod, did you encounter any issue when using the `gcloud auth list`? https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/list

Comment: Hi @FaridShumbar - when I run `gcloud auth list` I just get the account that I'm using with gcloud. I don't know how to access/view the permissions that the service account `google-billing@....` has using the `gcloud` commandline.